# How can I return a Future from a stream listen callback?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have below code in `flutter`:

```
getData() {
  final linksStream = getLinksStream().listen((String uri) async {
     return uri;   
  });
}
```

In `getData` method, I want to return the value of `uri` which is from a stream listener. Since this value is generated at a later time, I am thinking to response a Future object in `getData` method. But I don't know how I can pass the `uri` as the value of `Future`. 
In `javascript`, I can simply create a `promise` and `resolve` the value `uri`. How can I achieve it in `dart`?

Comment: `getLinksStream().single` or `getLinksStream().first`

Comment: I tried to call `await getLinksStream().single` but it doesn't return anything. It seems this method stuck there.

Comment: what about `first`?

Comment: yes, `first` works for me. What is the different between single and first?

Answer (score 6):

In your code 'return uri' is not returning from getData but returning from anonymous function which is parameter of listen.
Correct code is like:

```
Future<String> getData() {
  final Completer<String> c = new Completer<String>();
  final linksStream = getLinksStream().listen((String uri) {
     c.complete(uri);   
  });
  return c.future;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Future<String> getData() async{
  final linksStream = await getLinksStream().toList();
  return linksStream[0].toString();
}
```

Comment: `await getLinksStream().toList()` doesn't seem to return. It never goes to `return` statement.

Comment: print linkStream before the return